# Nested bind to member, need a pointer, got a reference. What do?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, bind, unique-ptr

I have a map of std::unique_ptr of type foo, and I'm trying to iterate the map, passing the value of each to a public member of a foo not in the map. I'm close, but I can't figure out how turn the result of the inner most bind from a reference to a pointer.

Given:

```
class foo
{
public:
    bool DoWork(foo *);
};

std::map<long, std::unique_ptr<foo> map_t;

map_t foo_map_;
foo bar_;

std::for_each(std::begin(foo_map_), std::end(foo_map_), std::bind(&Foo::DoWork, &bar_, std::bind(&std::unique_ptr<foo>::get, /* This guy here -->*/std::bind(&std::pair<long, std::unique_ptr<foo>>::second, std::placeholders::_1))));
```

Recommendations? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

Comment: I've always wondered about that. Where is the accept button? Edit: found it. Man, you'd be surprised, you'd think your UI is the most obvious in the world; I've never *SEEN* that check mark before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error is due to the fact that `std::map` const'ifies the key type, so that the `value_type` of `map_t` is not `std::pair<long, std::unique_ptr<foo> >` but rather `std::pair<long const, std::unique_ptr<foo> >`. To avoid such errors prefer using `map_t::value_type`. The following change fixes the error:

```
... std::bind(&map_t::value_type::second, std::placeholders::_1) ...
```

In C++11 you can simplify it to:

```
for(auto const& kv : foo_map_)
    bar_.DoWork(&*kv.second);
```

Or, using `std::for_each` and C++11 lambda:

```
for_each(foo_map_.begin(), foo_map_.end(), 
    [&bar_](map_t::value_type const& kv) { bar_.DoWork(&*kv.second); });
```

Comment: VC++ 2010 does not support range-based `for`; this is introduced in VC++ 2012.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simplicity is awesome..

You could simplify your code by using a pretty little *lambda*  instead of *std::bind*-madness, see the below snippet:

```
foo obj;

typedef std::map<long, std::unique_ptr<foo>> fooMap;

fooMap map_t;
```

```
std::for_each (
  map_t.begin (), map_t.end (), 
  [&obj](fooMap::value_type& elem) {
    obj.DoWork (elem.second.get ());
  }   
);
```